# Networked-Aframe changing buildings without refreshing the page?

Tags: aframe-networked

I have been using networked-aframe for a while and love it. I ben trying to figure out how I can change a bluding live without having to refresh the page itself. unfortunately my lack of coding skills I'm unable to figure out or do. I wanted to ask the A-frame or networked-aframe communinty If anyone knows how I can do that?

Joseph